# Top Questions: superuser Alltime

Tags: discussion, search

How do I search and explore **Top Questions: All Time** on superuser?

I thought I could be sneaky, and try "copy link address" and replace keyword **hot**, **week** or **month**

- https://superuser.com/?tab=alltime
- https://superuser.com/?tab=lifetime
- https://superuser.com/?tab=forever

Sadly, I didn't have any luck...I just wanna explore all the best content on superuser. It's almost ironic that I'm not able to do that.

[image: Where is the Top All Time Tab?!?]

Comment: Define "Top Question" Score? Number of answers? Number of Views?

Comment: Any of those I would be most grateful for, it's just about being able to consume the rich of information available. Darn...there is a super meta?! So many communities...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to create queries.

[Best answers created within 3 month range](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/291398/best-answers-created-within-3-month-range)

Use it for whatever site, or fork it and change answers to questions and 3 months to 1 year, whatever you want!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to find some results.

- https://superuser.com/questions?sort=votes

Works like the stack, I just replaced domain.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes